Meaning and usage of the phrasal verb "to bridge out"
Can 'bridge out' mean 'connect' or 'reach out'?
Here's an example I have in mind:

The artist's latest exhibition aims to bridge out to diverse communities, connecting different cultural perspectives through her paintings.


Have you checked a dictionary? What does it say?

@fev The dictionaries I can  use are not at all instructive about this term. You might let us in on  what those rarer works  you are thinking about have in store. (not in M-W, OLD, Collins, Cambridge, not apparently in the OED (https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=bridge+out), nor the SOED,  nor in Word Reference, nor in Dictionary.com, nor in the Am Heritage Dictionary, nor in longman Dictionary; its is in the Urban dictioanry (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bridge%20out), but in adjectival use))

In the context of your example, the exhibition promotes an openness to diverse communities.

It's a metaphor. You can use it if you like. Although "build a bridge to diverse communities" is maybe better and certainly more standard.

It's a transparent synonym of and modelled on 'reach out to'. It perhaps hints at a great effort intended / made.

Can 'bridge out' mean 'connect' or 'reach out'? No. I don't think "bridge out" is anything like a reasonable metaphor/alternative for to reach out. bridges are static, reaching is active. The Urban Dictionary entry does not have this meaning. No other dictionaries have entries (See LPH above) and, finally, in terms of electrical circuits to bridge something out would mean to bypass it. (See Wheatstone Bridge).

It’s trying to be trendy.

@Greybeard, bridges themselves, once their construction is completed, are indeed static, but the action of building a bridge (which is one of the dictionary meanings of bridge as a verb) is not.

To the OP: it is unclear what you mean by can in asking whether the phrase can be used that way. Obviously, it can in so far as somebody did actually use it that way. Can it convey the meaning of reach out? It can in so far as you, yourself understood it that way. Is it, as matter of style, a good idea to use the phrase that way? That's something on which people may differ.

However “bridge out” usually means that the bridge is not passable.

Actually a dictionary is not going to address this issue.

' ... Indeed, pupils seemed to intuitively bridge out to a bigger group when they felt they had resolution on an initial idea and would like to air it ...' [Michael Walsh; Let's Think in English]  I'd reserve it for reaching out to someone with help, not for help.

A big thank you for all your answers. I don't know how to answer each one individually. To sum it up, i couldn't find the answer in a dictionary, so i assumed it was possible to understand it in context. I used "can" because i seem to remember the phrase, but couldn't make out where and in which context, so i suggested an example. I understand the phrase is not too likely to be used as such, even if many English-speakers will understand it in context.

Fyi, I just visited a park website in the state of Massachusetts, and saw the verb to pack out, meaning: take your garbage out with you when you leave. Like I said in my answer, this bridge out makes use of the prep. out to create a new phrasal. pack out was completely new to me, just today!

bridge out here is an example of creativity within the bounds of what English can do. It has been used like a phrasal verb.

The artist's latest exhibition aims to bridge out to diverse communities.

To create a bridge between his/her works and other communities that may not be his/her own.
bridge out has the same grammar as fan out or spread out, for example.
The volunteers fanned out in pairs throughout the community.
